# How to modify the sequence of WSO2 APIM handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 APIM 1.10.0 with my custom handlers which are referenced [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers).

I have 2 global custom handlers:

1. HeaderSwapHandler
2. APIInforHandler

And I want these two custom handlers sequence as follows when the API created.

```
<handlers>
  <handler class="com.wso2.header.handler.HeaderSwapHandler"/>
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
     <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
  </handler>
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
     <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
     <property name="policyKeyApplication"
               value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/app-tiers.xml"/>
     <property name="id" value="A"/>
     <property name="policyKeyResource"
               value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/res-tiers.xml"/>
  </handler>
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
     <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
  </handler>
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
  <handler class="com.wso2.header.handler.APIInforHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

`HeaderSwapHandler` on the top and `APIInforHandler` on the bottom of the handlers.

Is there any way to do that?

**Edit and Solved**

My original `velocity_template.xml` is like:

```
<handlers xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<handler class="com.wso2.header.handler.HeaderSwapHandler"/>
<handler class="com.wso2.header.handler.APIInforHandler"/>
#foreach($handler in $handlers)
<handler xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" class="$handler.className">
    #if($handler.hasProperties())
    #set ($map = $handler.getProperties() )
    #foreach($property in $map.entrySet())
    <property name="$!property.key" value="$!property.value"/>
    #end
    #end
</handler>
#end
</handlers>
        #end
        #end
        #if($apiStatus == 'PROTOTYPED')
        #end
        ## end of apiIsBlocked check
         <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
         <property name="inline" value="INLINE"/>
      </handler>
       </handlers>
        </api>
```

Just change to:

```
<handlers xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<handler class="com.wso2.header.handler.HeaderSwapHandler"/>
#foreach($handler in $handlers)
<handler xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" class="$handler.className">
    #if($handler.hasProperties())
    #set ($map = $handler.getProperties() )
    #foreach($property in $map.entrySet())
    <property name="$!property.key" value="$!property.value"/>
    #end
    #end
</handler>
#end
<handler class="com.wso2.header.handler.APIInforHandler"/>
</handlers>
        #end
        #end
        #if($apiStatus == 'PROTOTYPED')
        #end
        ## end of apiIsBlocked check
         <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
         <property name="inline" value="INLINE"/>
      </handler>
       </handlers>
        </api>
```

That could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same page that you are referring, it has `Engaging the custom handler` section. It shows how you can use `velocity_template.xml` to engage your new handler to APIs.

Comment: Thanks @Bhathiya , just edit `velocity_template.xml` file could solve my problem.